# Index large pdf file into SOLR

Tags: solr

I am in the process of indexing a large pdf file into SOLR.
For text extraction I am using apache TIKA and SOLRJ for posting the files.
My current approach is to split each page into separate file and then extract (With apache TIKA) then post (with SOLRJ).
For accessing this information on UI(Custom UI),I need to have one field as-

**"url= http://localhost:8080/data/apache-solr-ref-guide-5.1.pdf#page=3"**
As you can see here I am capturing page number of each page for above mentioned url part.this is easy for me as I am splitting the whole file into multiple files.
everything works fine till now.

But now my requirement is to eliminate the process of splitting the files into multiple file.I mean,I want to extract full file without splitting into parts and at the same time in SOLR it should be stored as different pages,so that I can distinguish each page for creating URL.

Could you please let me know how to do that.?

Answer (score 2):

You could integrate everything into one code-base and reduce the layers.

So, use [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org) directly from SolrJ and ask it for page-by-page extraction which you then feed into Solr.

I would also look into creating parent/child records with child records representing each page and parent representing the whole document. This gives you more powerful search options down the line.